# Getting XMLHttpRequest error from POST request in flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart, http, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a post request to an API in flutter and it works perfectly when I use cURL on the command line but the request in flutter doesn't work. Tried a ton of different request formats but nothing works.

Here is the working cURL request: (the API correctly returns a string with details about the YouTube video)

```
curl -m 70 -X POST <API_URL_HERE> \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
-d '{"youtube_link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbUfbN7vT20"}'
```

Here is the not working Flutter request:

```
String link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbUfbN7vT20";
var url = Uri.parse("<API_URL_HERE>");
var response = await http.post(url, 
                  body: jsonEncode({"youtube_link": "$link"}), 
                  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
               );
```

Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
I checked on the server that is receiving the request. With the good request it returns a status code of 200 and on the Flutter request it returns a status code of 400 (but no errors are occurring in the actual code, it seems to be just a problem with the request).

Update:
Ok, it seems it was a CORS issue. However I haven't managed to fix it on the API side either by following these instructions
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests

although that is probably a separate question.

Comment: Are you running this in web or  mobile device ? if you are running it in web then its CORS issue that can be resolve by api side.

Comment: I'm running this on web. Another bit of information. I tried to change the request so that the link was being parsed as an arg (e.g. ?youtube_link=$link) and I saw on the server that the request actually finished with a status code of 200 after 5 seconds but on my end I still get the XMLHttpRequest error.

Comment: Thats CORS issue please ask API guy to allow CORS on their side

Comment: I created the api myself, I had a look to see whether it's possible to enable OPTIONS requests but I couldn't see anything. Is it possible to send the request as a normal POST request from flutter or not?

Comment: you created API using node.js or ?

Comment: I think I found a solution. One sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked out the fix:

The api is a python function on google cloud functions (the method would probably differ for different APIs)

You need to add the following code at the start and end of the function to accept a CORS request from flutter web.

```
def function(request):
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'custId, appId, Origin, Content-Type, Cookie, X-CSRF-TOKEN, Accept, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN, Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    # Set CORS headers for the main request
    headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    }

    ------ SOME CODE THAT DOES SOMETHING ------

    return(output,200,headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = Uri.http(base_url + '/register');
```

it will work

Answer (score -1):

You can user POST method in this way... Example of user register in my app

```
void register(User user) async {

var url = Uri.parse(base_url + '/register');

final http.Response response = await http.post(
  url,
  headers: <String, String>{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US',
  },
  body: json.encode(user.toJson()),
);

if (kDebugMode) {
  print(response.body.toString());
}
var answer = jsonDecode(response.body);
String returnAnswer = "";
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  try {
    ////code for success...
  } catch (_) {
    return returnAnswer;
  }
} else {
   ////Code/Message for failer
}}}
```